# ActiveRecord - List all parents DO NOT have one specific child

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a many-to-many relationship between users and badges.

```
class Badge < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :badges
end
```

A user can have many badges.

How can I efficiently list all the users who DO NOT have a specific badge id using ActiveRecord?

I have a lot of users and badges.

Comment: Yes, I know the badge id I don't want to find in users I select.

Comment: I'm not THAT noob anymore ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all the users where the user_id is not in the join table records with that badge id.

```
User.where('id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM badges_users WHERE badges_users.badge_id = ?)', badge.id )
```

Comment: Simple, I was trying to resolve that with left join and such, but I could simply access the relationship table. Thanks!